# Scale from this resolution

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding

I have the following mp4 file:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:04:43.66, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1704 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1080x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 1573 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
```

I want to scale it to 1280x720 and also change the aspect ratio to 16x9. I tried some settings from the documentation https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling but to no avail.

Comment: Please provide the command you used, as well as more detail about what went wrong; "to no avail" is a bit vague.

Comment: @stib I managed to solve it. The video had bars on the top and bottom, so in addition to using the scale filter I had to use the crop as well: `-vf "crop=in_w:in_h-110,scale=1280:720,setsar=1"`